# Why I'm Not Having Access to "$_POST" Data Outside My AJAX Callback?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, javascript

I'm trying to pass some data from the Back-end to *JavaScript*. The thing is, when I try to `console.log()` the variable passed through the `wp_localize_script()` it shows me on **Console** the structure that I've manipulated before, but without the actual data that I retrieved from the form.

---

### PHP Code

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_origin', 'create_an_ajax_request_origin_form' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_origin', 'create_an_ajax_request_origin_form' );
function create_an_ajax_request_origin_form() {
    $fields = array(
        'address'     => wp_kses( sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST[ 'origin' ][ 'address' ] ), array() ),
        'number'      => wp_kses( intval( absint( $_REQUEST[ 'origin' ][ 'number' ] ) ), array() ),
        'address_two' => wp_kses( sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST[ 'origin' ][ 'address_two' ] ), array() ),
        'city'        => wp_kses( sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST[ 'origin' ][ 'city' ] ), array() ),
    );

    $GLOBALS[ 'address_origin' ] = str_replace( array( 'Rua.', 'Rua', 'R.', 'R', 'Ru', 'Ru.', 'Ra', 'Ra.' ), array( '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ), $fields[ 'address' ] ) . ', ' . $fields[ 'number' ] . ' - ' . $fields[ 'city' ];
}

create_an_ajax_request_origin_form();
$GLOBALS[ 'address' ] = $address_origin;
```

Notice that I'm creating a *Global* variable, that retrieves the actual data (manipulated) sent from my **AJAX Request**.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueuing_script_for_origin_form' );
function enqueuing_script_for_origin_form() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'origin_form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sistema-de-entrega/origin-form.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    wp_localize_script( 'origin_form', 'origin', array(
        'admin_ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'address' => $GLOBALS[ 'address' ]
    ) );
}
```

And I would like to use that `$GLOBALS[ 'address_origin' ]` superglobal variable through out my entire code.

#### Example

Let's say that I have a function call `validate_address()` which receives the address manipulated from `create_an_ajax_request_origin_form()`. How can I have access to the **address** variable inside that *function*? And also through out my entire `.php` code?

---

### JavaScript Code

```
$.post( origin.admin_ajax, origin_data, function( response ) {
    console.log( origin.address, response );
} );
```

After passing it through the `wp_localize_script()` I'd like to work around with `origin.address` the way I want to inside the *JavaScript* code.

---

### The Output

> , 0 -

And this is what I should have seen from the **Console**.

> My Address, 200 - My City

It seems to me a *begginer*'s problem but I'm really confused about it and also can't get it to work right :/

---

### More Information

I forgot to say that if I `var_dump()` from the inside of `create_an_ajax_request_origin_form()` I get the address manipulated properly with the blanks all filled. I want to **filter** the data in the Back-end then pass it through the `wp_localize_script()`, and work with it the way I want in JavaScript.

Comment: I can't figure out the structure of your code, can you add more context? Where do you call `wp_localize_script`? What action are you passing and what is hooked to that action for your AJAX requests?

Comment: @Milo Well most of this structure is Brasilian Address based so, it basically `str_replace()` the address by removing all kind of text such as *Rua* which means *street* in portuguese and all it's variations, plus it concatenates all other information such as the *address* number and the city. I'll be editing this question by adding more code and perhaps some more context to make it clearer, alright?

Comment: I mean where are all of these bits of code relative to each other and in what order is everything happening? `wp_localize_script` is for printing a script tag to the page containing javascript when the script tag it is tied to is rendered to the page. it isn't for passing data from an AJAX callback, the page is already rendered.

Comment: I just added more code to the question and the code is ordered exactly as my `.php` file.

Comment: globals are global to the request they are defined in. the request that renders the page and your ajax request are two separate requests with no state shared between the two. `origin.address` is always the same because the only way it will change after the page is rendered is if you change it with javascript.

Comment: Then how can I change it with JavaScript @Milo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Maybe It's the Appropriate Answer for You!

Accordingly to this question the more reasonable answer is to use [`wp_send_json()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json) with (if only necessary) the `wp_send_json_success()` and `wp_send_json_error()` functions. They'll return an *JSON Object* back to the *AJAX Request* and it will automatically `die()` for you. It will look something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_origin', 'create_an_ajax_request_origin_form' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_origin', 'create_an_ajax_request_origin_form' );
function create_an_ajax_request_origin_form() {
    $fields = array(
        'address'     => wp_kses( sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'origin' ][ 'address' ] ), array() ),
        'number'      => wp_kses( intval( absint( $_POST[ 'origin' ][ 'number' ] ) ), array() ),
        'address_two' => wp_kses( sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'origin' ][ 'address_two' ] ), array() ),
        'city'        => wp_kses( sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'origin' ][ 'city' ] ), array() ),
    );

    wp_send_json( $fields ); // there's no need to use die() function if you're using wp_send_json()
}
```

If everything worked properly, now you might be able to reach those `$fields` data from inside the *AJAX Request*, and it'll look something like this:

```
$.post( origin.admin_ajax, origin_data, function( response ) {
    console.log( response.city ); // this will print out the response sent by the Backend through the wp_send_json() function
} );
```

> **Obs:** I changed the *superglobal* `$_REQUEST` variable to `$_POST`, which in my opinion is the most appropriate thing to do. Because we are using a `$.post` method to send and get the data between the **Frontend** and the **Backend**.

### The Real World Answer

Till that point I didn't know that I needed to extend the data into the **WordPress Dashboard**. So, the only option (in this case) was to get everything filtered by the `create_an_ajax_request_origin_form()` function and store it inside the *superglobal* `$_COOKIE` array.

I preferred to make use of [JavaScript Cookie Repository](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to deal with the *Cookies* in the *JavaScript*, that way made more sense of why I'm actually using Cookies.